# Creating a column that flags where any instance of a condition passes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has a list of customers and several variables against each of them. One of these is a conditional check based on their behaviour, a small example is below. What I want to do is, if ANY of the customers instances are False, mark all instances as False without changing the structure of the dataframe at all:

**Sample**

```
d = {'Customer': ['Cust 1', 'Cust 1', 'Cust 1', 'Cust 2', 'Cust 2', 'Cust 2', 'Cust 3', 'Cust 3'], 
     'Check': [True, True, False, True, True, True, True, False]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

  |Customer | Check |
  |---------|-------|
0 | Cust 1  | True  |
1 | Cust 1  | True  |
2 | Cust 1  | False |
3 | Cust 2  | True  |
4 | Cust 2  | True  |
5 | Cust 2  | True  |
6 | Cust 3  | True  |
7 | Cust 3  | False |
```

**Expected Output**

```
  |Customer | Check | Amended |
  |---------|-------|---------|
0 | Cust 1  | True  | False   |
1 | Cust 1  | True  | False   |
2 | Cust 1  | False | False   |
3 | Cust 2  | True  | True    |
4 | Cust 2  | True  | True    |
5 | Cust 2  | True  | True    |
6 | Cust 3  | True  | False   |
7 | Cust 3  | False | False   |
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) function, combined with [all](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.all.html) to see if all the values in `Check` per group is True. If there are any `False` then `False` will be returned for all entries in the group.

```
df.assign(Amended=df.groupby("Customer").Check.transform("all"))



Customer    Check   Amended
0   Cust 1  True    False
1   Cust 1  True    False
2   Cust 1  False   False
3   Cust 2  True    True
4   Cust 2  True    True
5   Cust 2  True    True
6   Cust 3  True    False
7   Cust 3  False   False
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks for that!. I was worried it would change the structure of the df, using group by, but nope! I think I need to practice that a bit more. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `prod`, since one `False` value equals `0` making the `prod` 0.

```
df['Amended'] = df.groupby('Customer')['Check'].transform('prod')

   Customer    Check   Amended
0   Cust 1     True    False
1   Cust 1     True    False
2   Cust 1     False   False
3   Cust 2     True    True
4   Cust 2     True    True
5   Cust 2     True    True
6   Cust 3     True    False
7   Cust 3     False   False
```